# Page not loading properly in IE 10

Tags: internet-explorer

My web pages are not fully loading on IE 10 running on Windows 8.
This is happening always.
A portion of the scrips, images, css etc seems to be not working.
Can anyone help me with this...

Thanks

Comment: Could you share your website link? It must have some broken/missing  resources and/or request at server-side blocking/slowing the response.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot share the link. This is happening on VisualForce pages and I am not supposed share the login credentials. Could you help me without the link to the pages?

Answer (score 1):

Can you press F12 inside of IE10 on the desktop. Check the browser mode and the standards mode, They should read IE10 and Standards mode. Take a look at the Console Tab and see if there are any error messages. Then go to the network tab, press "Start Capturing" reload the page and see if there are any 404 or server errors on any of the files. This might give us something to get going on.

If that leads to nothing. Go to Tools > Change User Agent String. Switch it to Chrome. Refresh the site, If the site starts working then you have some browser sniffing going on.

Comment: I have same issue. my page is working good in other browser but not into the IE. I did all above steps. but still it is not working. Is there any other issue with IE. Thanks